# Blend Alpha Crossover Operator in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operators, genetic-algorithm, blend, crossover

I use blend alpha crossover operator for a genetic algorithm (GA), but I encountered a problem as follows:

The chromosomes have the form: (parent1, parent2, parent3)
The values allowed for parent1, parent2, parent3 are in the range [0,1].

If you apply alpha blend crossover operator, the value of chromosomes can be outside the range [0,1] because this operator will expand the search space of GA.
In this case, what can I do to ensure that the range of values of the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Blended cross-over is supposed to choose values outside this range. This all depends on alpha. If you set alpha=0, it is the same of using uniform crossover.

You may decrease the alpha value or manually force the genes to remain within the range you want.

I hope it helps.